# Произведение элементов массива, расположенных между первым и последним нулевыми элементами массива

Tags: delphi, алгоритм

Ввести массив A[1..5] и число С. Для каждого элемента массива вычислить функцию:

```
B=c*sin2A-cosA.
```

Найти произведение элементов массива, расположенных между первым и последним нулевыми элементами массива.

Вопрос: Так что надо найти и как?

Comment: @Woronlida, А что именно не понятно? Задание вполне сносное.

Comment: Как правильно написать...

Comment: "Вопрос: Так что надо найти и как?"
Это вопрос к преподавателю(предположительно он задал задание). 
Мы тут не экстрасенсы.

Comment: У меня дополнительный вопрос: как правильно записать `sin2A`?


Comment: sin(power(a[i],2))

Answer (score 1):

Два цикла. В первом цикле ищете первый нулевой элемент:

```
if a[i]=0 then

begin

  first:=i;

  break;

end;
```

А во втором цикле ищете номер последнего нулевого элемента:

```
if a[i]=0 then

begin

  last:=i;

end;
```

Далее запускаете цикл от первого до последнего элемента, и считаете их произведение.

Answer (score 1):

Есть вопросы

1. Sin2a - это sin a * sin a или sin (2*a)?
2. Если нет нулевых элементов в массиве, что делать?

По ответам:

> Для каждого элемента массива вычислить функцию:

Это значит, что на выходе имеем массив B[5] значений функции для каждого из элементов массива A[5]